# Convert float to CharSequence in android?

Tags: java, android, floating-point, charsequence

I am making a throughput calculator where the user inputs data and the duration it took to download or upload and my intention is to display the throughput in varying units.

However, I cannot find a way to convert float to CharSequence so I can append it to my TextView.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This will also work - String s = "" + myFloat;

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
string s = Float.toString(myFloat);
```

Answer (score 9):

`String.valueOf(thisIsYourFloat)` will work.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
myFloat+""
```

.-